# NSLog only prints right value when I have a warning

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm getting garbage values when manipulating some of my `NSString` objects. I think the problem stems from my misunderstanding of how NSString works at a basic level. Below, I have a object which has a string pointer as a synthesized property. When I try to log it out directly, the compiler gives me a warning, but it does log out the value I expect. On the very next line, I try to log that string out the proper way but I end up getting garbage.

**Code snippet**

```
MyObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *myString = object.myString;
NSLog(myString); // format not a string literal and no formal arguments
NSLog(@"formatted = %s", myString);
```

**Output**

```
2011-05-16 13:06:51.137 MyProgram[917:207] thisValueIsGood
2011-05-16 13:06:51.138 MyProgram[917:207] formatted = `å
```

This problem has snowballed onto other functions which use this final string. When I concatenate that string with other strings, I get even more garbage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSString is an object, instead of `%s`, use `%@`.

Comment: Got it. Then I don't know what `%s` is good for... string literals? But why not just write the string literal in place of the `%s` instead? What is a practical use of `%s`?

Comment: @JoJo: `%s` is good for `char*` strings, like `"this string"`.  `%@` is for Objective-C objects, like `@"this string"`.  (The `@` makes it an `NSString` as opposed to a `char*`)